# Mpdf does not print when Mediawiki page includes pre-formatted text, without giving any errors

Tags: mediawiki, mpdf

I have Mpdf installed on my Mediawiki page and it works perfectly with all different pages. But when I have some pre-formatted text using the Pre tags it does not give out a print and it returns no messages or errors.
Has anyone had any experiences with this, or knows why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Tabs to edit your pre-formatted text, Mpdf cannot process it and it stops working without returning an error. I edited the text and gave the required spaces using the space key instead of Tab key, and the problem was solved.